# hiding passwords in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, security, passwords

I'm writing a bash script that needs login credentials (username and password) to make an API call. The script will eventually become a cron job, so it's not feasible to prompt the user for login credentials. What is the best way to hide the credentials in a bash script?

Comment: Can you not use encrypted strings.

Comment: Can you give an example for how I would do that?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is put the credentials in a file and make it readable to root only. Then run the script with sudo.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't set up restricted read permissions on the bash script itself (e.g. only root can read it), the usual approach is to use a separate file, with said restrictions (only root or a dedicated user can read it (chmod 400 filename)).

This is how you store your ssh keys in ~/.ssh/, as well.

If you are worried about someone having full access to your drive, e.g. someone stealing it, try cryptsetup/luks.

If you are worried about someone reading the unencrypted raw device, you might try breaking up the password, and assemble it in memory when needed...

Answer (score 0):

`SSHPASS=$_pass sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $_host`

I use this bit for instance and prompt user input to a restricted file, a bit more security not actually passing the variable during SSH session, but instead defining as an env variable.  Haven't had many concerns from my work place Security Engineers.  You can always do as others stated and have that file already containing creds rather than prompting and do the same here.